# Hide tooltip for Google Visualization API GeoChart

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a markers-based [Geochart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html) to display the location of schools.  I have my data in a Google docs spreadsheet.  I'm using 3 columns: lat, long and marker size.  Currently, the tooltips display lat and long.  Ideally, they would display information about each school instead but removing them would be fine, too.  See what I have so far [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lognaturel/WHL22/).

Some of the other Google visualizations seem to allow a trigger:'none' option for tooltip (e.g., [Pie Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html)).  Am I correct that there is no such thing for GeoChart?

It seems there's an [experimental feature](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/roles.html) that allows assigning a tooltip role to a particular data column.  I tried to use that to no avail.

I tried finding and hiding the tooltip div but I couldn't figure out how to access any elements in the iframe that contains the map.  I'd be perfectly happy with this kind of solution if I could get it to work!

I realize this is not exactly what Geochart seems meant for but I'm using other Geochart region maps on the same page and would like to keep the same aesthetic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you will be able to do exactly what you want at this time. However, I _do_ think that you should at least be able to improve the contents/UI of your tooltip; [this example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#geo_chart) from the  code playground at least titles the fields in each tip. Perhaps you could specify another 'description' column in your base spreadsheet, and feed that to the tooltip to achieve what you want?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, @oli.  That example also has a hardcoded tooltip that just displays the first two columns.  Mine looks particularly bad because my first columns are lat/long.  Did you find a way to make the tooltip use a description column?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe it can still help.

Check out this example:

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Lat');                                
data.addColumn('number', 'Long');
data.addColumn('string','tooltip');
data.addColumn('number','Example');                                 

data.addRows([[41.151636,-8.569336,'Portugal',{v:0,f:'test PT'}]]);
data.addRows([[ 39.059575,-98.789062,'USA',{v:1,f:'test US'}]]);
```

You can now also disable the tooltip adding, which was not previously available:

```
tooltip.trigger:'none';
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmoreira/njB6m/